# Python mongoengine QuerySet returns unexpected values

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have defined `dbSMS` class on top of `mongoengine.Document` like this (I imported `mongoengine` as `db`):

```python
class dbSMS(db.Document):
    sender = db.StringField(max_length=12, required=True)
    target = db.StringField(max_length=12, required=True)
    message = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    status = db.StringField(required=False)
    meta = {
        'collection': 'sms',
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)
```

When I manually create new object of this class I can access its members. But when I try to query database for specific objects of this class, it returns something... well, strange.
This is the code I use to query the database and print the contents of result:

```python
self.buffer = dbSMS.objects(sender__in = self.phones, status = 'on hold')
            for sms in self.buffer:
                print("dbSMS type: {}".format(type(sms)))
                print("dbSMS sender {}".format(sms.sender))
                print("dbSMS target {}".format(sms.target))
                print("dbSMS message {}".format(sms.message))
```

It should return several dbSMS object that contain members and their values, but here's output:

```
dbSMS type: <class 'sms.dbSMS'>
dbSMS sender ()
dbSMS target {'sender': '+79000000000', 'message': 'Тест', '_updated': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 26, 13, 19, 29), '__only_fields': [], '__auto_convert': False, '_created': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 26, 13, 19, 29), '_etag': '2132f429984474ccb9755e021a1fbe4c6823ab01', 'target': '+79000000000', 'id': ObjectId('5b323d61e13823081b1db7ff'), 'status': 'on hold'}
dbSMS message None
```

As you can see, the type of returned objects is indeed dbSMS, but when I try to access its members, it gives me empty tuple, dict with members and their values and None.
Mongoengine documantation states this:

> The QuerySet object may be iterated over to fetch documents from the
>   database

Hence, I expected to see objects of the class I defined.

So, what am I doing wrong? Maybe I defined `dbSMS` class in the wrong way, or have I failed to understand what `dbSMS.objects` does exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, turns out I defined `dbSMS` the wrong way. QuerySet returned me `args` and `kwargs` and I totally ignored them in `__init__` and just blindly passed them to parent class. Here's how it works now:

```
class dbSMS(db.DynamicDocument):
    sender = db.StringField(max_length=12, required=True)
    target = db.StringField(max_length=12, required=True)
    message = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    status = db.StringField(required=False)
    meta = {
        'collection': 'sms',
    }
```

I got rid of whole `__init__` altogether and changed parent class to `DynamicDocument` (because I might require that kind of scalability). Now it works exactly as expected.

Hope my stupid silly mistake helps someone.